# Crashlytics report could not be enqueued to DataTransport

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-analytics

I am having trouble with crashlytics, crash reports are not being sent.
here it is the logcat trace:

```
I/FirebaseCrashlytics: Initializing Firebase Crashlytics 18.2.11 for me.easymobile.instantnfc
D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics automatic data collection ENABLED by API.
D/FirebaseCrashlytics: AnalyticsConnector now available.
D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Registered Firebase Analytics listener.
D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Mapping file ID is: 00000000000000000000000000000000
D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Checking for cached settings...
D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Loaded cached settings: {"settings_version":3,"cache_duration":86400,"features":{"collect_logged_exceptions":true,"collect_reports":true,"collect_analytics":false,"prompt_enabled":false,"push_enabled":false,"firebase_crashlytics_enabled":false,"collect_anrs":true,"collect_metric_kit":false},"app":{"status":"activated","update_required":false,"report_upload_variant":2,"native_report_upload_variant":2},"fabric":{"org_id":"62b4a28bc05d8f12c0fb9a2c","bundle_id":"me.easymobile.instantnfc"},"on_demand_upload_rate_per_minute":10,"on_demand_backoff_base":1.2,"on_demand_backoff_step_duration_seconds":60,"expires_at":1656371952637}
D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics automatic data collection ENABLED by API.
D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Successfully configured exception handler.
D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Opening a new session with ID 62B9C225023700014690853C61CBF100
D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Registered Firebase Analytics event receiver for breadcrumbs
D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics automatic data collection ENABLED by API.
D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Automatic data collection is enabled. Allowing upload.
D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics automatic data collection ENABLED by API.
D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Sending cached crash reports...
D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Sending report through Google DataTransport: 62B9BBED01AE000139B3853C61CBF100
D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Sending report through Google DataTransport: 62B9B501014000012F4B853C61CBF100
D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Sending report through Google DataTransport: 62B9B47D000E00012DBC853C61CBF100
D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Sending report through Google DataTransport: 62B9B3C4007300012BD5853C61CBF100
W/FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics report could not be enqueued to DataTransport
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Log tag "TRuntime.SQLiteEventStore" exceeds limit of 23 characters
        at android.util.Log.isLoggable(Native Method)
        at com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.logging.Logging.d(Logging.java:64)
        at com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.persistence.SQLiteEventStore.persist(SQLiteEventStore.java:104)
        at com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.DefaultScheduler.lambda$schedule$0$com-google-android-datatransport-runtime-scheduling-DefaultScheduler(DefaultScheduler.java:83)
        at com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.DefaultScheduler$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.execute(D8$$SyntheticClass)
        at com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.persistence.SQLiteEventStore.runCriticalSection(SQLiteEventStore.java:754)
        at com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.DefaultScheduler.lambda$schedule$1$com-google-android-datatransport-runtime-scheduling-DefaultScheduler(DefaultScheduler.java:81)
        at com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.DefaultScheduler$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(D8$$SyntheticClass)
        at com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.SafeLoggingExecutor$SafeLoggingRunnable.run(SafeLoggingExecutor.java:47)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

crashlytics configuration seems to be ok, as the console is displaying the following message:

```
 App detected and we're waiting for a crash!
```

gradle files are configured as defined here

[https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?hl=da&platform=android#kotlin+ktx](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?hl=da&platform=android#kotlin%20ktx)

I have spent hours trying to find out what is wrong, but had no luck.
Any help would be most appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/3823

Comment: I checked that issue before, and noticed it was reported as fixed so I thought it was not a problem anymore. You made me go check again, and now I noticed it was fixed only a few days ago.. so it is not yet released!!. I downgraded the firebase dependency versions and now everything works fine. Thanks!!

Comment: I actually had a question since you already had that on production. Does the app just disable crashlytics reporting or there’s an ugly crash at startup? Thanx.

Comment: It is not a fatal crash. the app continues running, but it keeps logging the warning every time crashlytics attempts to enqueue a cached crash report to the DataTransport. Regards

Comment: Ahh alright, thanks for confirming.

Comment: Have you upgraded your crashlytics version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just downgraded the firebase dependencies versions from

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx:18.2.11'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:21.0.0'
```

to

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx:17.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:19.0.0'
```

until the fixes are released.